# Are there any guidelines on modal/wizard approach when making UX for information kiosks?

Tags: wizard, kiosk, modal-windows

Is it ok to use modal windows or should use only linear wizards?

For example, when I've some kind of wizard process finished by entering payment details or signinig it with digital signature, should those last steps be included in wizard or made as separate modal?

And, are there any global guidelines on implementation of UI/UX for information kiosk stands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are. They are described in detail in About Face 3 (by Alan Cooper) and maybe earlier versions as well (I can't check since I only have version 3). The main guielines are:

- Make your click/touch targets large enough: 20 mm should be enough.
- Use soft-keyboard input sparingly: awkward for user and creates lots of fingerprints (which make the screen look dirty)
- Avoid drag 'n drop: can be difficult to master on touch screen

I must say, i don't know if the last one is as relevant today as it was when the book was written (2007). Most people now have their own touch-devices and are more familiar with the gestures that go along with it.

The book elaborates more on this topic and I strongly recommend to you to read it in full.

Comment: But that's only half of answer - what about modals/wizards?

Comment: I think things like 'avoid drag and drop' and 'a minimal hitarea' can be applied to modals/wizard (on touch screens), since they are part of the kios-axperience. Can you elaborate?